# Can enemies charge through, walk through, or even go through Witch Thorns and other walls?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, wall

I was playing as my Wizard and I was up against a golem protecting some treasure. I was all alone in a small room, and to block the entrance and prevent the golem from getting to me, I used the power *Witch Thorns:*

> ## Witch Thorns
>
> Wall 3 within 10 squares, The wall creates a zone that lasts until the end of the encounter. The zone can be up to 4 squares high and must be on solid surface. The zone can provide partial cover and blocks line of sight. The zone is difficult terrain. and when any attempts to leave a square in the zone, the creature must succeed on a saving throw or be immobilized until the start of its next turn. Once per round as a minor action, you can expand or contract the zone by 2 squares in any direction.

I thought this basically sealed up the entrance and made sure the golem couldn't get to me or even see where I was, but the DM had the golem just charge through it. The DM said that its just normal difficult terrain and it can get through the wall.

I don't know the rules about walls, but I guessed that the reason for making walls is so that creatures have to climb over them or go around them to get to you. Is that true that enemies can go through your walls?

Comment: Could someone with access to the rules text update the power to be a bit more accurate to its actual rules text, keywords etc? This seems to contain some typographical errors, and shorthand which might omit something important.

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely. They just have to make their save.

Difficult terrain is not blocking terrain. The only part of this power that stops movement is the saving throw when the creature leaves. If your DM did not have the Golem take and then make the save, then it was played incorrectly. If the golem passed his save, and paid the extra movement for the difficult terrain, then it was played correctly.

This isn't exactly a *wall*. It's more of a thicket. Yeah, it's tough to get through, and you might get stuck, but generally, you *can* move through it, even if it takes you an extra turn. The "wall" keyword on the power is actually a zone descriptor and dictates how you can lay down the power. See the rules for Wall powers on pg: 110 of the Rules compendium.